# Stage3D could not be found in IntelliJ and Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, starling-framework

I have installed Air SDK 3.8 and Flex 4.10. I merged Air SDK into Flex directory. I downloaded Starling 1.3.0.

I added Flex SDK and Starling swc into the classpath of IntelliJ.

I can run a simple AS3 HelloWorld application from inside IntelliJ. But when I run a simple HelloWorld application for Starling, IntelliJ gives the following error after completing compilation:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.display::Stage3D could not be found
```

Comment: may be flash player is too old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following line to index.template.html solves the problem:

```
params.wmode = "direct";
```

Note that this line should be added before the following line:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(...
```